# why why my customer directive does not work?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-directive

My main purpose is to use customer directive to show different pages depend on the user login  or logout

```
    <!-- Show this for logged out users -->
    <ul *appShowAuthed="false"
        class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">
                Sign up
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- Show this for logged out users -->
    <ul *appShowAuthed="true"
        class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a 
                class="nav-link" 
                routerLink="/"
                routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

my customer directive

```
 import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appShowAuthed]'
})
export class ShowAuthedDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private userService: UserService,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  condition: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.isAuthenciated.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated) => {
        if (isAuthenticated && this.condition || !isAuthenticated && !this.condition) {
          this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  @Input() set appShowAuthed(condition: boolean) {
    this.condition = condition;
  }

}
```

I import it in my header module

```
import { ShowAuthedDirective } from './../show-authed.directive';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ShowAuthedDirective
    ],

    imports: [],
    providers: []
})

export class headerModule {}
```

> but when I launch it, in google chrome it show this: core.js:7813 Can't bind to 'appShowAuthed' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'

Comment: yes, sure it did solve my problem. thanks, varman. but there is another question i would like to ask. this idea is I inspire by the conduit project(https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/app/shared/layout/header.component.html) where * is used as a custom directive prefix, is that because of the angular version??? the late version has removed  * if u use your own customer directive???

Comment: If the answer helps you, please click on tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 1):

You should have `CommonModule` under your imports array on your `headerModule`

```
import { ShowAuthedDirective } from './../show-authed.directive';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ShowAuthedDirective
    ],

    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    providers: []
})

export class headerModule {}
```

### Update

There's a `*` prefixed on the HTML. It should be removed

Comment: I try that way, but it didn't work. but now I fix my problem,  I just remove *  before appShowAuthed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove * mark from `*appShowAuthed`. Because you use a custom directive.

I've made a simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gythfa?file=src/app/auth.directive.ts) to show how its working. You can see the console when you move mouse-over on both elements